# is it possible to export/create the external table file from hive create external table command to a remote server

Tags: hadoop, ftp, hive, sqoop

is it possible to export/create the external table file from hive create external table command to a remote server.

```
create external table SOME_TABLE (MY_Coulmns) 
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n' 
stored as textfile location '<Remote server A with IP XXXXX and with username and password>';
```

**Requirement**: I have to export this file/data from hive to Cassandra (on a different server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using IP with username and password for external storage through Hive is not a good practice as it can become a security issue. From Hive you can easily use external [Amazon S3 storage](https://blog.mustardgrain.com/2010/09/30/using-hive-with-existing-files-on-s3/) or [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage/) instead.

**EDIT**: Alternately, use [**Hive Cassandra Storage Handler**](https://github.com/tuplejump/cash/tree/master/cassandra-handler) (org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql.**CqlStorageHandler**) as the Storage Handler for your Hive table if you are able to access Cassandra host and port directly from Hive. This will simplify your work greatly as Hive will be able to write directly to external table in Cassandra.

Comment: I have to export this file/data from hive to Cassandra (on a different server). Anything else that I can try ?

Comment: You can export files from HDFS using FTP and then use a custom parse/load script on the destination server to load into Cassandra. For FTPing files from HDFS, you can try using HDFS-OVER-FTP (https://github.com/iponweb/hdfs-over-ftp, https://sites.google.com/a/iponweb.net/hadoop/Home/hdfs-over-ftp). If you do not want to use HDFS-OVER-FTP, you will need to write your own custom Java based FTP Action which can be run on Oozie. Obviously option-2 (i.e building your own Java FTP Action) is going to be more difficult than option-1. In fact there is a OPEN ticket for the FTP requirement - HDFS-217.